# Jquery .focus() not working without tabindex attribute of div

Tags: jquery

How can I make jquery `.focus()` to work without setting tabindex of a div

```
  $("#msgdiv").focus();

<div id="msgdiv" tabindex="100"> </div>
```

what is the best practise for this

what i want to achieve: After changing the password i want to display the acknowledgment message that the password has been changed and put focus on that div.

Comment: Please post some of your code..show what you have tried to do so far..

Comment: i want to ask is this the good practise?

Answer (score 6):

Simply, you can't do focus on a div without tabindex, see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

Don't really know what you wanna achieve with this code-snippet, but if you wanna trigger a focus event, you should use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$("#msgdiv").trigger('focus');
```

Answer (score 4):

the div needs a tabindex in order to receive focus, you can set one via the jQuery before the `focus()` function, without having to manually add it to the HTML though -  if that's what you're asking

```
$("div").attr("tabindex",-1).focus(function() { 
// do something
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A div can only receive focus if it has the tabindex attribute.

What do you actually want to achieve here?

Comment: hidden field also doesn't do focus for me

Comment: i'm guessing it shouldn't. why would you even need this?