# how to check whether a div is focused or not in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use kendo grid in my view, I want to create new row in the grid after pressing enter key. I can do this by writing following code:

```
<div id="GridContainer">
<div id="grid"></div>
</div>

$(document.body).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();
}
});
```

The problem is, on the page, whenever I press enter, its creating new row. But I want that only when the grid is focused. How can I do that? I tried to apply focus to the div, that contains the grid, but no luck. I skipped the code to generate the kendo grid for readability. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid" tabindex="0"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="grid" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document.body).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $("#grid").is(':focus')) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();
    }
});
```

Read [How can I give keyboard focus to a DIV and attach keyboard event handlers to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148361/how-can-i-give-keyboard-focus-to-a-div-and-attach-keyboard-event-handlers-to-it)
And
[Jquery .focus() not working without tabindex attribute of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594431/jquery-focus-not-working-without-tabindex-attribute-of-div)

**Updated**

`Focus` the `div` again after adding a `row`, like,

```
$(document.body).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $("#grid").is(':focus')) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();
        $("#grid").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can You please help me a bit more? I need to create new row every time I press enter. but with current code, after pressing once it's not creating any row. If I'm not wrong, its loosing focus of the grid. How can I keep the focus?

Comment: Means You want the `addition` of `row` will `fire` only once?

Comment: no, I want to fire the event every time user press the enter button but only when he is working with the grid, that is the grid is in focus.

Comment: The above code will work `when` your `div#grid` is `focused`.

Comment: its not working that way, after clicking the grid, if I press enter, it adds a row, but after that no new row!

Comment: You mean to say that when the `div` is focused and you `press enter key`, then it will not add any row?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in my previous comments. Let me explain, The current scenario is, after loading the page, I need to click the grid first to focus it, then if I press enter it adds the new row as expected, but if I again press the enter, its not adding the new row anymore. But I want to add new row until I mouse click some other content on the page but grid, that is to shift the focus from grid. Hope It makes things clear.

Comment: I want to add new row until the focus is shifted from the grid, but now after adding one row, somehow the focus getting shifted, no new row is being created.

Comment: test the above I've made changes in it,

Comment: Ok, I think we need to check if we are in the last column of the last row! let me try this.